# How can I make the third box move under second box using CSS

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML and CSS, If the container is less than 600px wide, I want the blue box to move under the pink box instead of under the red one.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0hp7Lbh/)

HTML

```
<div class="row" id="one">
    &nbsp;
</div><div class="row" id="two">
    &nbsp;
</div><div class="row" id="three">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

CSS

```
#one{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
#two{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
}
#three{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.row{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Side note: The odd formatting of "</div><div" prevents unwanted spaces between the inline(-block) elements.

Comment: Then you need to `float` the red box to the left … http://jsfiddle.net/s0hp7Lbh/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what else you have in your page but if you simply add `float: left;` to the red div. It will sit under the pink div as you desire.

Then add a media query for when above 600px to remove the float.

```
@media(min-width: 600px) {
  #one { float: none; }
}
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Haha, no worries :D Thanks for provisionally accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Give float:left to red block

```
#one {
    float:left
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```